# Generate correlated data in Python (3.3)

Tags: python, r, numpy, scipy, correlation

In R there is a function (`cm.rnorm.cor`, from package `CreditMetrics`), that takes the amount of samples, the amount of variables, and a correlation matrix in order to create correlated data.

Is there an equivalent in Python?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, on Python 3.3.

Comment: Whaaat... Support got added really recently! Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @Dualinity, on a less humoristic tone, beside the great collection of packages from Blender, I really suggest you try Python(X,Y). It's a collection of Python packages for scientific development + IPython + Great IDE called spyder. http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/

Comment: Hah, well, I'm using Emacs... so I'm taken care of in the "IDE" department...

Comment: I can't believe that after trying so long... Scipy has been installed. The question still holds, but I'll remove the "without SciPy" part.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The method [`multivariate_normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.multivariate_normal.html) of the `Generator` class in `numpy.random` is the function that you want.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


num_samples = 400

# The desired mean values of the sample.
mu = np.array([5.0, 0.0, 10.0])

# The desired covariance matrix.
r = np.array([
        [  3.40, -2.75, -2.00],
        [ -2.75,  5.50,  1.50],
        [ -2.00,  1.50,  1.25]
    ])

# Generate the random samples.
rng = np.random.default_rng()
y = rng.multivariate_normal(mu, r, size=num_samples)


# Plot various projections of the samples.
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(y[:,0], y[:,1], 'b.', alpha=0.25)
plt.plot(mu[0], mu[1], 'ro', ms=3.5)
plt.ylabel('y[1]')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.plot(y[:,0], y[:,2], 'b.', alpha=0.25)
plt.plot(mu[0], mu[2], 'ro', ms=3.5)
plt.xlabel('y[0]')
plt.ylabel('y[2]')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.plot(y[:,1], y[:,2], 'b.', alpha=0.25)
plt.plot(mu[1], mu[2], 'ro', ms=3.5)
plt.xlabel('y[1]')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: scatter plots]

See also [CorrelatedRandomSamples](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/CorrelatedRandomSamples.html) in the SciPy Cookbook.

Answer (score 11):

If you Cholesky-decompose a covariance matrix `C` into `L L^T`, and generate an
independent random vector `x`, then `Lx` will be a random vector with covariance
`C`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
linalg = np.linalg
np.random.seed(1)

num_samples = 1000
num_variables = 2
cov = [[0.3, 0.2], [0.2, 0.2]]

L = linalg.cholesky(cov)
# print(L.shape)
# (2, 2)
uncorrelated = np.random.standard_normal((num_variables, num_samples))
mean = [1, 1]
correlated = np.dot(L, uncorrelated) + np.array(mean).reshape(2, 1)
# print(correlated.shape)
# (2, 1000)
plt.scatter(correlated[0, :], correlated[1, :], c='green')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Reference: See [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Monte_Carlo_simulation)

---

If you want to generate two series, `X` and `Y`, with a particular [(Pearson) correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence#Pearson.27s_product-moment_coefficient) (e.g. 0.2):

```
rho = cov(X,Y) / sqrt(var(X)*var(Y))
```

you could choose the covariance matrix to be

```
cov = [[1, 0.2],
       [0.2, 1]]
```

This makes the `cov(X,Y) = 0.2`, and the variances, `var(X)` and `var(Y)` both equal to 1. So `rho` would equal 0.2.

For example, below we generate pairs of correlated series, `X` and `Y`, 1000 times. Then we plot a histogram of the correlation coefficients:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats
linalg = np.linalg
np.random.seed(1)

num_samples = 1000
num_variables = 2
cov = [[1.0, 0.2], [0.2, 1.0]]

L = linalg.cholesky(cov)

rhos = []
for i in range(1000):
    uncorrelated = np.random.standard_normal((num_variables, num_samples))
    correlated = np.dot(L, uncorrelated)
    X, Y = correlated
    rho, pval = stats.pearsonr(X, Y)
    rhos.append(rho)

plt.hist(rhos)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see, the correlation coefficients are generally near 0.2, but for any given sample, the correlation will most likely not be 0.2 exactly.

Comment: Would you know how to get data to be exactly having a correlation of, say, 0.2 (with like a small tolerance)?

Comment: What's `numpy.random.multivariate_normal` doing under the hood? Because I compared the former with the cholesky approach and found the latter to be significantly faster, particularly for larger dimensional data (like a few thousand). Does the cholesky approach only work for some specfic types of covariance matrix? My cov-matrix is only diagonal, or very sparse.

Comment: @Jason `multivariate_normal` uses SVD rather than Cholesky