# How can I generate a gaussian process with correlation?

Tags: python, numpy

I can generate a gaussian process with `np.random.normal(0,1)`.  This GP is uncorrelated.  How can I generate a gaussian process with correlation?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024677/generate-correlated-data-in-python-3-3

Answer (score 1):

I think [`numpy.random.multivariate_normal(mu, cov)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html) does just what you need.

You can also generate it with:

```
assert cov.shape == (N, N)
assert mu.shape == (N,)

L = np.linalg.cholesky(cov)
process = mu + L.T @ np.random.normal(0,1,N)
```

but this will fail for singular covariance matrices

---

Remember that you can only generate *samples* from a Gaussian process, since a process has infinitely many values