# How do I sample from a correlation matrix, given a starting mean and standard deviation, in Python

Tags: python, correlation, covariance, sampling

Say I have this correlation matrix specifying the relationship between different variables:

```
corr_matrix = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1.0,-0.5,0.2],'B':[-0.5,1.0,0.8],'C':[.02,0.8,1.0]},index=['A','B','C'])
```

[image]

and I also have a dataframe that specifies the individual means and standard deviations of those same variables:

```
mean_and_std_df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','C'],'Mean':[5,3,6],'Standard Deviation':[1.2,0.2,0.5]})
```

[image]

Lastly, I have a constraint that says the sum of A, B and C cannot exceed 14.

I'd like to generate many random samples that follow the logic of the correlation matrix relationship between the variables, while also keeping in mind the mean and standard deviation of each variable, while not exceeding 14. How would I do this?

For example:

A and B have a negative correlation of -0.5. Since A's mean is 5, and standard deviation 1.2, maybe in one sample generation we have A = 7, B = 2, and 5.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Agree with @Prune. To get you started, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024677/generate-correlated-data-in-python-3-3