# Generate two random arrays according to correlation coefficient

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

For example, I know the correlation coefficient between Array1 and Array2 is 0.68, and the length of Array1 and Array2 are 100. How to generate the random value for Array1 and Array2? Thanks in advance.

> Update

One method provided by Michael Szczesny is using the [multivariate_normal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024677/generate-correlated-data-in-python-3-3), but if I give the `r = [ [1,0],[0,4] ]` and I will get two arrays. Using the two arrays to calculate the r is not 0, but 0.05 (for example). how to explain this?

Comment: There is no example code in this question. Have you tried something?. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate correlated data in Python (3.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024677/generate-correlated-data-in-python-3-3)

Comment: Thanks Michael, this helps. For Muhammad, I want to generate two random arrays but I don't konw how to reach this. Thnaks.