# Python generate 3 correlated array of random noise with different distributions

Tags: python, statistics, probability, correlation, vector-auto-regression

I need to generate random noise for 3 variables, i.e. `X`, `Y` and `Z`. I need `X` to be lognormal, and `Y` and `Z` is normal. The correlation matrix should be:

```
1, -0.8, 0.5
-, 1,   -0.5
0.5,-0.5,  1
```

The std of `X` and `Y` and `Z` should be 0.5, 0.3 and 20. The mean of `X` and `Y` should be 1, and 0 for `Z`. How can I do that?

I know I can use [Generate correlated data in Python (3.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024677/generate-correlated-data-in-python-3-3) to generate 3 normally distributed. So how can I apply it to my case?

I think I can firstly generate `X1=log(X)`, `Y` and `Z` at first. But how can I set the correlation matrix? i.e. if the `corr(X, Y)=-0.8`, what is `corr(log(X), Y)`?

-----advanced version

what if I want `X` and `Y` and `Z` all be AR(1) process?

Thanks!